# how to autoarrange the elements in EA

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I want to create elements and add them to a diagram from C# using this method:

```
DiagramObjects.AddNew("l=100;r=300;t=100;b=150;", "").
```

Without using this API, how can we auto-resize the elements in the diagram view and auto-arrange if it the diagram contains multiple elements?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
Repository.GetProjectInterface.LayoutDiagramEx (string DiagramGUID, long LayoutStyle, long Iterations, long LayerSpacing, long ColumnSpacing, boolean SaveToDiagram)
```

to automatically layout a diagram. See also the [help details](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.1/automation_and_scripting/project_2.html).

The API has no method to auto-size elements. However, this seems to auto-size on creation:

```
DiagramObjects.AddNew("l=100;t=-100", "")
```

Note that the y-coordinate goes from 0 (top) to negative (bottom).

P.S. I just found that Alt-Z will increase the size of the element a bit. The above creates a minimum size.

Comment: I have 10 elements in the diagram If i try the above method for autoarranging it not working.Please provide the above method with argument values to autoarrange the 10 elements in the diagram

Comment: Looking into EAConstants in the scripting window you will find lsInitializeNaive = &H08000000 to be supplied as LayoutStyle. Or choose another one from the constants nearby.